# How can I speed this python code up?

Tags: python, primes

I have made some code that calculates prime numbers (Nothing special I know) and as expected it slows down the bigger the number, I know it is impossible to make it the same speed no matter the number but I am sure I could improve it's speed, I just don't know how...

```
import time
number = 1000000001
count = 0
start = time.time()
while number > 1000000000 and number < 10000000000000:
    for i in range(1, round(number/2 + 1)):
        if (number / i).is_integer():
            count += 1
        if count > 1:
            break
    if count < 2:
        print(str(number) + ' prime')
    number = number + 1
    count = 0
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n)

Comment: First of all Python is slow. Secondly, there are lots of very advanced and difficult to understand algorithms for finding primes. This is not a topic for 5min talk.

Comment: Use a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @khelwood according to http://primesieve.org/, even that would take about a day - 25h - to run, for the 10T limit. trial division would run for years, or maybe centuries, who knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things:

- you do not have to check from `1`, but `3`, `5` and all *odd* numbers;
- you do not have to check until *n/2*, but you can stop at *sqrt(n)*;
- do not use division, since then you work with floating points, but use `%` to check modulo;
- you only have to check odd numbers (or two); and
- you can omit the greater than check in the while loop, since the number only increments.

So an improved version would be:

```
import time
from math import sqrt # import square root

start = time.time()

for number in range(1000000001,10000000000000,2): # use for, hops of 2
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(number))+1,2): # check 3, 5,... up to sqrt(n)
        if number % i == 0: # use modulo checks instead of floating point
            break
    else: # use a for-else structure for faster ending
        print(str(number) + ' prime')
    count = 0
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Nevertheless, Python is not designed to get the most out of a CPU. If you really want to code a superoptimized algorithm, you will have to pick a faster (and less convenient) programming language.

Comment: You can use `for n in range(number, 10000000000000, 2)`. `for` loop is faster than `while` loop.

Comment: this is very helpful, i have also noticed if i do not print the primes and instead append them to a list and print of the list when finished it is much faster.